# C++: how to access data stored in in 2d static arrays and use it functions?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, static

I am trying to work with some RGB pallets stored in static 2d arrays:

```
double colorA[600][3] ={
{1.25432,1.23453,1.234523}
{1.345234, 1.2345234, 1.2345}
..........
....
};

double colorB[782][3] ={
{1.5433,1.3453,1.2345}
{1.135, 215, 1.31422}
..........
....
};

double colorC[456][3] ={
{1.454,1.343,1.234}
{1.345, 1.6543, 1.21421}
..........
....
};
```

Then if user chooses to work with colorB, I would like to get it into a function to process some calculations:

```
String userColorChoice = "colorA";
....
if (userColorChoice ==  "colorA" )
      doStuff(colorA);
```

My problem is that I don't know how to pass colorA as an argument in doStuff() function since the number of rows is not the same from color to color. Should I store the colors in a different way? I tried vectors but since I have a lot of colors the compiling time exploded!

Comment: What does **dostuff** do?

Comment: "Should I store the colors in a different way? I tried vectors but since I have a lot of colors the compiling time exploded!" You either have to pass them as separate arguments or actually use modern C++ with `std::array`, `std::vector`, even though I would still recommend a flattened array with shape passed separately. I do not see how *compilation* time would explode, can you show an example?

Comment: I created 30 colors in vectors and added them in a map <Key(String) , Color<>  >. As I started uncommenting the colors one by one the compilation time went to 8 minutes when I had 10-15 colors. Could it be the map slowing down the process?

Answer (score 0):

Use STL container

```
struct Color {
    double r,g,b;
};

void doStuff(const std::vector<Color>& color) {

}

...

std::vector<Color> colorA, colorB, colorC;
std::vector<Color>* choosenColor = nullptr;

// fill colors
{

}

if(some_cond) {
    choosenColor = &colorB;
}

if(choosenColor) {
    doStuff(*choosenColor);
}
```

Comment: Since color data is fixed, would it be possible to save it in the stack and call it instead of using dynamically allocated vectors? It is around 10000 x 4 doubles.